# Adding a UIView behind a UITableView causes tableview's content insets to be wrong aligned to topLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, mkmapview

I have to show an `UIMapView` behind an `UITableView` into a controller in a way that the **mapView** becomes visible "behind" the tableview's header (similar to foursquare's "nearby places" view) with the typical parallax effect.

I've laid out my tableview within storyboards, added the **mapView** as a **Container View** behind the tableView, I've tried this in two ways: via storyboard and programmatically with something like:

```
[self.view addSubview: self.mapView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.mapView];
```

but in both cases the tableview's header ends under the navigation bar, I suppose by losing its reference to the toplayoutguide.

this is a screenshot of the view in storyboards:

[image]

and this is the result on the simulator:

[image]

As you can see, tableview's header starts under the navigation bar and not under the **topLayoutGuide** as it should.
Now, if I don't add any subview behind the tableview anything seems to work as expected, but I need the map behind so it is no use.

I've found a workaround with this code snippet placed into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
        UIEdgeInsets currentInsets = self.tableView.contentInset;    
        self.tableView.contentInset = (UIEdgeInsets){
            .top = self.topLayoutGuide.length,
            .bottom = currentInsets.bottom,
            .left = currentInsets.left,
            .right = currentInsets.right
        };
    }
}
```

But, it seems too much of a hack in first place, and also, tableview's `contentInset` starts at -64, not a big mess but I just don't like it.

My question so far is: why is this all happening and how can I fix it, if possible, in a more precise way?